# C converting a char to string

Tags: c

trying to convert char to a string in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int x = 80;
    char buffer[1] = {0};
    buffer[0] = (char) x;
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

and I got "PP". 
Why the result is "PP" instead of "P"?

Comment: Your buffer is too small, it can only hold a single char - no room for the zero terminator

Comment: Because this is not a proper zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

When calling

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

your string should be null terminated. When you assign buffer[0] you are left with a 1 char long "string" without '\0' as its last character.
Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    int x = 80;
    char buffer[2] = {0};
    buffer[0] = (char) x;
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have enough space for `'P'` you should change this `char buffer[1]={0};` 
to 
`char buffer[2]={0};`.note you always need to terminate the string , but in your initialization `char buffer[2]={0};` zero will be cast to char , so char `\0` will be place in every character of your string.

Comment: @kwl1888 feel free, there is no need for thanks , but accept the answer if this was  helpful.